# How do you carry a dog on a bike?

Tags: cargo, animals

Over the years I have seen a few people transport a dog on a bike.  What options have you seen?   Please include a photo in your answer if possible.

Comment: "Very carefully" ;)

Comment: I would think the dog that's on the bike can pedal, and won't need to be carried.

Comment: You don't, dogs like to run.

Comment: If you're on a motorized 2-wheeler, make sure your dogs wear helmets or leather biker hats. Don't forget the [Doggles](http://www.doggles.com/dog/eyewear)!

Comment: Cargo bikes work very well - the dog sits in the load box on a squab and is leashed down, if there's a chance they will jump out.

Comment: Mira uses a plastic crate on a rear rack. https://bikepacking.com/news/john-and-mira-dogpacking-world-tour-ep-1-montana/

Answer (score 15):

I just googled "Bike Dog trailer" and got tonnes of results.  I have heard that trailers from "WIKE" are good.  Here is a pic of their biggest dog trailer:

[image: wike trailer]

I have also seen a few DIY dog trailers.

I like this quite a bit.  The dog is just tied in so they don't jump around but they still get a good view.  Found at [Bike Trailer Blog](http://www.biketrailerblog.com/2010/06/bob%E2%80%99s-diy-bike-trailer-solutions-part-2/)

[image: diy]

There is also the option to mount the dog's crate onto the trailer.  I have seen lots of pictures of these. Basically you just need to put some bolts through the flatbed of the trailer. This is a more professional example [from Tony's Trailers](http://www.tonystrailers.com/dog/):

[image: tony trailers example]

I guess in theory you could also put a small dog in your front basket, but I would not do that.  If the dog moves around that will make your bike unstable, also the dog may try to jump out causing a crash.

Comment: I'm thinking that anything other than a trailer like these is an accident waiting to happen.  I've not tried a dog on my bike yet, but I can  say from personal that a squirmy person on the back of a motorcycle can send you off the road!  I'm guessing that the lower mass of the bike offsets the lower mass of the dog and could result in a similar circumstance.

Comment: Lesson learnt: I own a trailer like this which is big enough to transport 2 dogs with ease. I found my dogs barked a lot, so best have the person who the dogs consider the alpha to be cycling behind them initially till they get used to it. The trailer is more agile than I imagined, a bit on the heavy side though for long distances and uphill. And what happened to me was my bike was stolen, so I lost the PIN side of the trailer which was on my bike. I would recommend, when not in use detaching the pin side on the bike always.

Answer (score 4):

I've never used one of these, but [these Snoozer baskets](http://www.snoozerpetproducts.com/snoozer-sporty-pet-bike-basket-p-83.html) look good for small dogs:

[image]

The [folks on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0019W2DBM) sure seem to like their other model, but that one doesn't specify if it includes a leash clip. Just remember: safety first. Get your best friend some [Doggles](http://doggles.com/).

Answer (score 3):

I've been using a K9 Sport Sack for my 25 pound dog. https://www.k9sportsack.com
The dog and I ride a couple times a week. It took awhile for my back and shoulders to get used to the weight but it's no problem now.

We have a bike trailer for dogs and have used it once. The backpack is much less of a hassle. No need for extra bike attachments. No storage concerns. No difference in bike handling when I use it. Rough surfaces don't jostle the dog around because my legs and back absorb the bumps.

My dog actually gets upset if I ride without him. He ended up liking riding more than walks and more than going to the park.[image][image]

Comment: _"My dog actually gets upset if I ride without him. He ended up liking riding more than walks and more than going to the park."_ So don't get one of these? 

Answer (score 3):

I love cycling with dogs (only remember to fasten them with a seat belt ). To transport a dog, I use a cargo bike from Ferla https://ferlafamilybikes.com/, for me, it turned out to be the most convenient option.

[image]